# Is there a uniswap v2 router for arbitrum (how to trade arbitrum using ethers.js)?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

I can not find a uniswap v2 router for any network other than ethereum mainnet.

In the uniswap v2 documentation, I find a uniswap router address, "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D on the Ethereum mainnet, and the Ropsten, Rinkeby, Görli, and Kovan testnets". In the deployment contracts section, I find only the factory addresses, no router addresses. I want to use uniswap v2 on the arbitrum network. How can I do this? Sushiswap has an arbitrum router address documented, but uniswap's solution is not clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Uniswap v2 just recently has been "officially" deployed their factory on all networks with v3 support. The factory addresses are provided in this forum post:
https://gov.uniswap.org/t/temperature-check-deploy-uniswap-v2-on-all-chains-with-v3/21799/12

For swapping, it's possible to use the `UniversalRouter` deployed on all these chains. There are no official `SwapRouter` deployments on these chains, nor there are plans for that as far as I know. If someone needs that for integration purposes, they can deploy it themselves, or search for "unofficial" deployments that have exact binary code match (with the exception of some chains like zkSync which are not fully EVM compatible, so the  router's bytecode will be different).